# Set-builder notation and the notion of function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My understanding of set-builder notation is that given a set $A$ and a function $P:A\to\{true,false\}$, one can define the subset
$$
B=\{a\in A:P(a)\} .
$$
However, a function $f:A\to C$ is defined as a special kind of subset of the product set 
$$
A\times C= \{(a,c):a\in A,\,c\in C\}.
$$
I was wondering if there is any circularity here, since we are using the set-builder notation to define the Cartesian product of two sets. I also imagine that in order to define the set of functions from $A$ to $C$ one needs to use set-builder notation.

Comment: Generally, we work with a formula in some formal logic rather than with a function $P : A \to \{\text{true}, \text{false}\}$. We can define formulae in a recursive fashion without needing to define set-builder notation, avoiding this problem.

Comment: @qaphla: Thanks a lot! Are you saying that some preliminary version of the set-builder notation must be defined before defining the full notation?

Comment: Usually, the [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) is an abbreviation; thus, it is part of the *syntax*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks! Can you please expand on that a bit? Are you saying that one should not use the set-builder notation?

Comment: MO copy of the question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241517/set-builder-formula

Comment: @timur - no, I'm not saying that. We introduce it as an abbreviation to "name": *the set of those $x$ such that $\varphi(x)$ holds of them, provided that that set exists*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [axiomatic set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), what you described as [set-builder notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation) corresponds to [axiom schema of specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) (also called axiom schema of separation).

As already said in the comments, $P(a)$ in this axiom schema does not stand for function but for a formula in the language of set theory.

[Axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) is related to the notion of function.

---

In fact, if you want to define [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Most_common_implementation_.28set_theory.29) in [axiomatic set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) you

- Use [Kuratowski definition of ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski_definition), i.e., $(a,b)=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$. It can be shown that for any $a$, $b$ the ordered pair $(a,b)$ exists; that $(a,b)=(a',b')$ iff $a=a'$ and $b=b'$; that $(a,b)\in\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A\cup B))$ if $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.
- Then you can define $$A\times B = \{x\in \mathcal P(\mathcal P(A\cup B)); (\exists a\in A)(\exists b\in B) x=(a,b)\}.$$

This means that the Cartesian product is defined using [axiom schema of separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) (which is written using set-builder notation). And, as you rightly said, function is then defined as a subset of Cartesian product which has some additional properties.

---

If you want to see a formal definition of formula (as used in the ZFC), for example, it is described nicely in [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](http://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/ZFC).
Basically, you have the following rules:

1. For any variables $x$, $y$, the atomic formulas $x=y$ and $x\in y$ are formulas.
2. If $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are formulas, then so are $\neg\varphi$, $\varphi\land\psi$, $\varphi\lor\psi$, $\varphi\Rightarrow\psi$ and $\varphi\Leftrightarrow\psi$.
3. If $\varphi$ is formula, then so are $(\forall x) \varphi(x)$ and $(\exists x) \varphi(x)$.

Anything constructed by applying the above rules finitely many times is considered a formula. And nothing else is considered a formula.

So an example of a formula would be $$(\forall x) (x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B).$$ This formula corresponds to $A\subseteq B$.

Comment: Great! Is it correct to think that a formula is basically a combination of symbols taken from a dictionary of allowed symbols, by using certain rules on how one can combine those symbols, sort of like how we define elementary functions in calculus?

Comment: Yes. You are allowed to use atomic formulae $x=y$ and $x\in y$ (where $x$ and $y$ are variables.) And you can combine them using logical connectives and quantifiers.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for bothering you, this is my last question: Is a formula simply a Boolean function whose inputs are atomic formulas?

Comment: I don't think that you are allowed quantifiers in Boolean functions. For example, you want $A\subseteq B$ expressed as $(\forall x) (x\in A \Rightarrow x\in B)$ to be a formula.

Comment: If you want see formal definition of formula (as used in the ZFC), it should not be difficult to find some resources. For example, searching for [ZFC language formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=ZFC+language+formula&tbm=bks) returns some reasonable hits.

Comment: @timur I have posted a more precise definition of formula [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/2318/2016/6/6). (I did not want to post too many comments here.) If further clarifications are needed, we can continue our discussion there.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I took the liberty of editing your answer to include the discussion about formulas, in case other people find it useful.

Comment: @timur: I'm not sure if you got the point, but formulae are simply strings of symbols. They are utterly devoid of meaning until you interpret them. Now in set theory the intended interpretation is that every object is a set, and so formulae like "$x \in y$" always make sense regardless of what $x,y$ are. The axiom of specification is a **syntactic** rule that says that you can use any existing object $S$ and any formula $φ$ with no free variables except $x$ to construct a new object denoted by $\{ x : x \in S \land φ \}$. Only in our intended interpretation is it a subset of $S$.

Comment: @timur: Note that although functions in set theory are defined to be sets of a certain kind, not all function-like things are functions. For example the powerset operation is **not** a function because if it is then its domain would have to be the set of everything, but existence of such a set allows Russell's paradox leading to contradiction.